# Problem with quotes inside System.assertEquals

Tags: apex, visualforce, code-coverage

```
System.assertEquals('/apex/?id=' + account.Id + \'&Object=Account&doclist=\' + Template.Id', pageRef.getUrl());
```

I am testing a page reference in my test class but the quotes around '&Object=Account&doclist=' is creating me trouble and therefore I have enclosed them in a ' before and after but I still seem to have a problem.

Here is the original URL which I am trying to assert

```
/apex/DOC__?id=' + Id + '&Object=Account&doclist=' + template_id
```

> Error : Unrecognized symbol '', which is not a valid Apex identifier.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need quotes around variable names, and you're not trying to use quotes in a string. Your code should look like:

```
System.assertEquals(
  '/apex/SDOC__SDCreate1?id=' + 
  employer.Id + 
  '&Object=Account&doclist=' + 
  sdocTemplate.Id, 
  pageRef.getUrl()
);
```